# Error connecting to PostgreSQL 9.4 with MIT Kerberos via JDBC vs CLI

Tags: java, postgresql, authentication, jdbc, kerberos

I have set up PostgreSQL 9.4 with MIT Kerberos 5 and CAN connect on the CLI using psql. After filing off the fingerprints my principal is bgiles/postgres@REALM, the pg_hba.conf has

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0        gss include_realm=1 map=gss krb_realm=REALM
```

and the pg_ident.conf file has

```
gss     /^(.*)/postgres@REALM$ \1
```

I created that principal, saved it to a keytab, and if I

```
$ kinit -k -t krb5.keytab bgiles/postgres
```

I can successfully connect to my PostgreSQL server 'kpg'. This proves the Kerberos and keytab are set up properly.

```
$ psql -h kpg dbname
(connection information...)
```

However when I use the same keytab to connect via JDBC I get a GSS Authentication Error which is due to PostgreSQL refusing to perform the mapping.

```
2016-04-20 00:13:16 UTC [18919-1] bgiles/postgres@bgiles LOG:  no match in usermap "gss" for user "bgiles/postgres" authenticated as "bgiles/postgres@REALM"
2016-04-20 00:13:16 UTC [18919-2] bgiles/postgres@bgiles FATAL:  GSSAPI authentication failed for user "bgiles/postgres"
2016-04-20 00:13:16 UTC [18919-3] bgiles/postgres@bgiles DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host    all     all     75.144.16.201/32    gss include_realm=1 map=gss krb_realm=REALM"
```

(I noticed the @bgiles and suspect this is key to the problem but am totally stumped by it.)

The test code is

```
public class KerberosPostgreSQLTest {

    static {
        URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("jaas.conf");

        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", url.toExternalForm());
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", "REALM");
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc", "kdc");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://kpg/bgiles";
        String user = "bgiles/postgres";

        Properties connInfo = new Properties();
        connInfo.put("user", user);
        connInfo.put("jaasApplicationName", "pgjdbc");

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, connInfo)) {

        }
    }
}
```

and the JAAS configuration file is

```
pgjdbc {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    refreshKrb5Config=true
    doNotPrompt=true
    useTicketCache=true
    renewTGT=false
    useKeyTab=true
    keyTab="/tmp/krb5.keytab"
    debug=true
    client=true
    principal="bgiles/postgres"
    ;
```

};

The PostgreSQL database definitely recognizes a valid Kerberos connection attempt. It's balking at the final step where it maps from Kerberos principal to PostgreSQL user id. Somehow the java/jaas/jdbc code is mangling it and something that works on the CLI does not work via JDBC.

I have used countless variants of the boolean flags and adding or removing @REALM and found many ways to prevent GSS authentication from happening at all but nothing lets me connect to the server.

Any ideas? The only difference is in the java/jaas/jdbc code but I can't understand how it can get a mangled principal that's still accepted by the KDC. TGT issues?

Thanks,

Bear

Comment: Were you able to fix this?