# Connect to Postgres DB with Kerberos from Java/Windows7

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, kerberos

I've looked everywhere and asked loads of people but no one is able to help me so far. I'm trying to connect to a postgres (9.6) database on a remote machine from my windows (7) laptop through a Java (8) application. We use Kerberos for securing access but i have a valid Kerberos account and can create tickets via de Ticket Manager. I can also log on to other 'services' which require Kerberos authentication, although not through java but via a browser.

But whatever i try, i can't get my java program to work. Here's what i've got:

krb5.ini

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = <domain>
forwardable = true
kdc_timesync = 1
ccache_type = 4
proxiable = true
dns_lookup_kdc = true
dns_lookup_realm = true

[realms]
<domain>.NET = {
    admin_server = <domain-server>
    default_domain = <domain>
}

[domain_realm]
.<domain> = <domain>
<domain>  = <domain>
.local.nl.<company>.com = <domain>
local.nl.<company>.com = <domain>
 [login]
krb4_convert = true
krb4_get_tickets = false
```

jaas.conf:

```
pgjdbc {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
refreshKrb5Config=true
doNotPrompt=false
useTicketCache=false
renewTGT=false
useKeyTab=true
keyTab="<location>/<filename>.keytab"
debug=true
client=true
principal="<username>@<domain>";
};
```

.keytab file

```
public class KerberosPostgresClient {
static {
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf","c:/tmp/krb5.ini");
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm","<domain>");
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc","<domain>");
        System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly","false");
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config","c:/tmp/jaas.conf"); }

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://<hostname>:<port>/<database>";
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("JAASConfigName", "pgjdbc");
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, connInfo)) {
        conn.createStatement();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The very simple java code can find the keytab, jaas.conf. I created the keytab file on a different machine but with the same principal and password.

When i run the program i see:

```
Debug is  true storeKey false useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt false ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is c:/tmp/<username>.keytab refreshKrb5Config is true principal is <username>@<domain> tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
Refreshing Kerberos configuration
```

and after a short while i get an exception:

```
[Krb5LoginModule] authentication failed 
Receive timed out
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: GSS Authentication failed
at org.postgresql.gss.MakeGSS.authenticate(MakeGSS.java:65)
....    
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketReceiveOrPeekData(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:120)
at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:144)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:812)
at sun.security.krb5.internal.UDPClient.receive(NetClient.java:206)
at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm$KdcCommunication.run(KdcComm.java:411)
at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm$KdcCommunication.run(KdcComm.java:364)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(KdcComm.java:348)
at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.sendIfPossible(KdcComm.java:253)
at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(KdcComm.java:229)
at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(KdcComm.java:200)
at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.send(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:316)
at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.action(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:361)
at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:776)
... 45 more
```

I used to get other exceptions which indicated that it couldn't find the keytab file but with the above setup it seems to work. I can also ping the postgres database from my machine.

I found: [Error connecting to PostgreSQL 9.4 with MIT Kerberos via JDBC vs CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36731871/error-connecting-to-postgresql-9-4-with-mit-kerberos-via-jdbc-vs-cli) but has no solution

Comment: When I see socket timeout on receive my first thought is a firewall issue.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your input. I can recall someone else mention that, the stacktrace implies it's using UDP and that might be blocked by the firewall(?) . If that is the case, how can i set it to use TCP/IP

Comment: Update: added "udp_preference_limit=1" to the krb5.ini to use TCP, but now i get "connection timed out", so i think you are right in that it's a firewall issue. It is strange that other people, although they use Macs can connect to the database. I'll check with the DBA'ers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i finally got it working with the following settings in my jaas.conf:

```
pgjdbc {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
refreshKrb5Config=true
doNotPrompt=true
useTicketCache=true
renewTGT=true
useKeyTab=true
keyTab="c:/<locationto>/<user>.keytab"
debug=true
client=true
principal="<user>@<domain>";
};
```

namely the combination of doNotPrompt, useTicketCache, renewTGT finally got it working